# Buildozer (No main.py(c) found in your app directory) but i have it inside the root folder

Tags: python, flask, buildozer, p4a

first post here on StackOverflow. I'm trying to build an android app with buildozer. It's primarily a web app made using Flask and Python, but when i try to build it i receive this error:

```
WARNING: Received a --sdk argument, but this argument is deprecated and does nothing.
BUILD FAILURE: No main.py(c) found in your app directory. This
file must exist to act as the entry point for you app. If your app is
started by a file with a different name, rename it to main.py or add a
main.py that loads it.
# Command failed: ['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pythonforandroid.toolchain', 'apk', '--bootstrap', 'sdl2', '--dist_name', 'playlisthelperbyponce', '--name', 'Playlist Helper by Ponce for Spotify', '--version', '0.1', '--package', 'ponce.playlisthelperbyponce', '--minsdk', '21', '--ndk-api', '21', '--private', '/home/roberto/Desktop/SpotiPy/.buildozer/android/app', '--android-entrypoint', 'org.kivy.android.PythonActivity', '--android-apptheme', '@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar', '--orientation', 'portrait', '--orientation', 'landscape', '--orientation', 'landscape-reverse', '--enable-androidx', '--copy-libs', '--arch', 'arm64-v8a', '--arch', 'armeabi-v7a', '--color=always', '--storage-dir=/home/roberto/Desktop/SpotiPy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a', '--ndk-api=21', '--ignore-setup-py', '--debug']
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/roberto-VirtualBox:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1351,unix/roberto-VirtualBox:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1351'
#     QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'
#     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg'
#     SSH_AGENT_LAUNCHER = 'gnome-keyring'
#     XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'gnome-'
#     GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID = 'this-is-deprecated'
#     LC_ADDRESS = 'it_IT.UTF-8'
#     GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE = 'ubuntu'
#     LC_NAME = 'it_IT.UTF-8'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
#     XMODIFIERS = '@im=ibus'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     LC_MONETARY = 'it_IT.UTF-8'
#     GTK_MODULES = 'gail:atk-bridge'
#     DBUS_STARTER_BUS_TYPE = 'session'
#     PWD = '/home/roberto/Desktop/SpotiPy'
#     LOGNAME = 'roberto'
#     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu'
#     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'wayland'
#     SYSTEMD_EXEC_PID = '1351'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/run/user/1000/.mutter-Xwaylandauth.NPSY91'
#     HOME = '/home/roberto'
#     USERNAME = 'roberto'
#     IM_CONFIG_PHASE = '1'
#     LC_PAPER = 'it_IT.UTF-8'
#     LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.webp=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu:GNOME'
#     VTE_VERSION = '6800'
#     WAYLAND_DISPLAY = 'wayland-0'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN = '/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/128fb806_d2a6_407a_b441_066d23033d4a'
#     GNOME_SETUP_DISPLAY = ':1'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     XDG_SESSION_CLASS = 'user'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     LC_IDENTIFICATION = 'it_IT.UTF-8'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     USER = 'roberto'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE = ':1.125'
#     DISPLAY = ':0'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     LC_TELEPHONE = 'it_IT.UTF-8'
#     QT_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     LC_MEASUREMENT = 'it_IT.UTF-8'
#     DBUS_STARTER_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus,guid=28bc1e8e77e09856f642f45164e5f327'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
#     LC_TIME = 'it_IT.UTF-8'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     PATH = '/home/roberto/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/roberto/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin'
#     GDMSESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus,guid=28bc1e8e77e09856f642f45164e5f327'
#     LC_NUMERIC = 'it_IT.UTF-8'
#     _ = '/home/roberto/.local/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/roberto/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/roberto/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/roberto/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '31'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

the buildozer.spec is a the root of the folder structure of the app, as well as the main.py file.

I'm running an Ubuntu 22.04 virtual machine.

Hope you can help me, thanks <3

I already deleted all hidden folder (I read somewhere that having hidden folders could make this error appear).

I already followed this post [BUILD FAILURE: No main.py(o) found in your app directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61362147/build-failure-no-main-pyo-found-in-your-app-directory)

This is my folder structure:

- bin(created by buildozer)
- static

  - here css, images and JS
- templates

  - here all htmls
- venv

  - here virtual environment created when i was programming the web app
- .buildozer(created by buildozer)
- app.yaml (for Google App Engine)
- buildozer.spec
- Dockerfile (for Google App Engine)
- gunicorn.conf.py (for Google App Engine)
- main.py
- requirements.txt (for Google App Engine)
- Functions.py

Here's my spec file:

```
[app]
 
# (str) Title of your application
title = Playlist Helper by Ponce for Spotify
 
# (str) Package name
package.name = playlisthelperbyponce
 
# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = ponce
 
# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .
 
# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = #py,png,jpg,kv,atlas
 
# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png
 
# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec
 
# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin, venv
 
# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
# Do not prefix with './'
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg
 
# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py
 
# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3, kivy, Spotipy, Flask, python_dateutil, Bootstrap-Flask, WTForms, gunicorn, Flask-Session
 
# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy
 
# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png
 
# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png
 
# (list) Supported orientations
# Valid options are: landscape, portrait, portrait-reverse or landscape-reverse
orientation = portrait, landscape, landscape-reverse
 
# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY


        #
        # OSX Specific
        #
         
        #
        # author = © Copyright Info
         
        # change the major version of python used by the app
        osx.python_version = 3
         
        # Kivy version to use
        osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1
         
        #
        # Android specific
        #
         
        # (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
        fullscreen = 1
         
        # (string) Presplash background color (for android toolchain)
        # Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
        # red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
        # darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
        # olive, purple, silver, teal.
        #android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF
         
        # (string) Presplash animation using Lottie format.
        # see https://lottiefiles.com/ for examples and https://airbnb.design/lottie/
        # for general documentation.
        # Lottie files can be created using various tools, like Adobe After Effect or Synfig.
        #android.presplash_lottie = "path/to/lottie/file.json"
         
        # (str) Adaptive icon of the application (used if Android API level is 26+ at runtime)
        #icon.adaptive_foreground.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon_fg.png
        #icon.adaptive_background.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon_bg.png
         
        # (list) Permissions
        # (See https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/buildoptions/#build-options-1 for all the supported syntaxes and properties)
        #android.permissions = android.permission.INTERNET, (name=android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;maxSdkVersion=18)
         
        # (list) features (adds uses-feature -tags to manifest)
        #android.features = android.hardware.usb.host
         
        # (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
        #android.api = 31
         
        # (int) Minimum API your APK / AAB will support.
        #android.minapi = 21
         
        # (int) Android SDK version to use
        #android.sdk = 20
         
        # (str) Android NDK version to use
        #android.ndk = 23b
         
        # (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
        #android.ndk_api = 21
         
        # (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
        #android.private_storage = True
         
        # (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
        #android.ndk_path =
         
        # (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
        #android.sdk_path =
         
        # (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
        #android.ant_path =
         
        # (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
        # This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
        # when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
        # android.skip_update = False
         
        # (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
        # agreements. This is intended for automation only. If set to False,
        # the default, you will be shown the license when first running
        # buildozer.
        # android.accept_sdk_license = False
         
        # (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
        #android.entrypoint = org.kivy.android.PythonActivity
         
        # (str) Full name including package path of the Java class that implements Android Activity
        # use that parameter together with android.entrypoint to set custom Java class instead of PythonActivity
        #android.activity_class_name = org.kivy.android.PythonActivity
         
        # (str) Extra xml to write directly inside the <manifest> element of AndroidManifest.xml
        # use that parameter to provide a filename from where to load your custom XML code
        #android.extra_manifest_xml = ./src/android/extra_manifest.xml
         
        # (str) Extra xml to write directly inside the <manifest><application> tag of AndroidManifest.xml
        # use that parameter to provide a filename from where to load your custom XML arguments:
        #android.extra_manifest_application_arguments = ./src/android/extra_manifest_application_arguments.xml
         
        # (str) Full name including package path of the Java class that implements Python Service
        # use that parameter to set custom Java class which extends PythonService
        #android.service_class_name = org.kivy.android.PythonService
         
        # (str) Android app theme, default is ok for Kivy-based app
        # android.apptheme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
         
        # (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
        #android.whitelist =
         
        # (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
        #android.whitelist_src =
         
        # (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
        #android.blacklist_src =
         
        # (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
        # their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
        # down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
        # OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
        #android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar
         
        # (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
        # directory containing the files)
        #android.add_src =
         
        # (list) Android AAR archives to add
        #android.add_aars =
         
        # (list) Put these files or directories in the apk assets directory.
        # Either form may be used, and assets need not be in 'source.include_exts'.
        # 1) android.add_assets = source_asset_relative_path
        # 2) android.add_assets = source_asset_path:destination_asset_relative_path
        #android.add_assets =
         
        # (list) Put these files or directories in the apk res directory.
        # The option may be used in three ways, the value may contain one or zero ':'
        # Some examples:
        # 1) A file to add to resources, legal resource names contain ['a-z','0-9','_']
        # android.add_resources = my_icons/all-inclusive.png:drawable/all_inclusive.png
        # 2) A directory, here  'legal_icons' must contain resources of one kind
        # android.add_resources = legal_icons:drawable
        # 3) A directory, here 'legal_resources' must contain one or more directories,
        # each of a resource kind:  drawable, xml, etc...
        # android.add_resources = legal_resources
        #android.add_resources =
         
        # (list) Gradle dependencies to add
        #android.gradle_dependencies =
         
        # (bool) Enable AndroidX support. Enable when 'android.gradle_dependencies'
        # contains an 'androidx' package, or any package from Kotlin source.
        # android.enable_androidx requires android.api >= 28
        #android.enable_androidx = True
         
        # (list) add java compile options
        # this can for example be necessary when importing certain java libraries using the 'android.gradle_dependencies' option
        # see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support for further information
        # android.add_compile_options = "sourceCompatibility = 1.8", "targetCompatibility = 1.8"
         
        # (list) Gradle repositories to add {can be necessary for some android.gradle_dependencies}
        # please enclose in double quotes
        # e.g. android.gradle_repositories = "maven { url 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor' }"
        #android.add_gradle_repositories =
         
        # (list) packaging options to add
        # see https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html
        # can be necessary to solve conflicts in gradle_dependencies
        # please enclose in double quotes
        # e.g. android.add_packaging_options = "exclude 'META-INF/common.kotlin_module'", "exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'"
        #android.add_packaging_options =
         
        # (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
        #android.add_activities = com.example.ExampleActivity
         
        # (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
        # If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
        #android.ouya.category = GAME
         
        # (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
        #android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png
         
        # (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
        #android.manifest.intent_filters =
         
        # (list) Copy these files to src/main/res/xml/ (used for example with intent-filters)
        #android.res_xml = PATH_TO_FILE,
         
        # (str) launchMode to set for the main activity
        #android.manifest.launch_mode = standard
         
        # (str) screenOrientation to set for the main activity.
        # Valid values can be found at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element
        #android.manifest.orientation = fullSensor
         
        # (list) Android additional libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
        #android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
        #android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
        #android.add_libs_arm64_v8a = libs/android-v8/*.so
        #android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
        #android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so
         
        # (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
        # Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
        #android.wakelock = False
         
        # (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
        #android.meta_data =
         
        # (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
        # project.properties automatically.)
        #android.library_references =
         
        # (list) Android shared libraries which will be added to AndroidManifest.xml using <uses-library> tag
        #android.uses_library =
         
        # (str) Android logcat filters to use
        #android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D
         
        # (bool) Android logcat only display log for activity's pid
        #android.logcat_pid_only = False
         
        # (str) Android additional adb arguments
        #android.adb_args = -H host.docker.internal
         
        # (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
        #android.copy_libs = 1
         
        # (list) The Android archs to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64
        # In past, was `android.arch` as we weren't supporting builds for multiple archs at the same time.
        android.archs = arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a
         
        # (int) overrides automatic versionCode computation (used in build.gradle)
        # this is not the same as app version and should only be edited if you know what you're doing
        # android.numeric_version = 1
         
        # (bool) enables Android auto backup feature (Android API >=23)
        android.allow_backup = True
         
        # (str) XML file for custom backup rules (see official auto backup documentation)
        # android.backup_rules =
         
        # (str) If you need to insert variables into your AndroidManifest.xml file,
        # you can do so with the manifestPlaceholders property.
        # This property takes a map of key-value pairs. (via a string)
        # Usage example : android.manifest_placeholders = [myCustomUrl:\"org.kivy.customurl\"]
        # android.manifest_placeholders = [:]
         
        # (bool) Skip byte compile for .py files
        # android.no-byte-compile-python = False
         
        # (str) The format used to package the app for release mode (aab or apk or aar).
        # android.release_artifact = aab
         
        # (str) The format used to package the app for debug mode (apk or aar).
        # android.debug_artifact = apk
         
        #
        # Python for android (p4a) specific
        #
         
        # (str) python-for-android URL to use for checkout
        #p4a.url =
         
        # (str) python-for-android fork to use in case if p4a.url is not specified, defaults to upstream (kivy)
        #p4a.fork = kivy
         
        # (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
        #p4a.branch = master
         
        # (str) python-for-android specific commit to use, defaults to HEAD, must be within p4a.branch
        #p4a.commit = HEAD
         
        # (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
        #p4a.source_dir =
         
        # (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
        #p4a.local_recipes =
         
        # (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
        #p4a.hook =
         
        # (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
        # p4a.bootstrap = sdl2
         
        # (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
        #p4a.port =
         
        # Control passing the --use-setup-py vs --ignore-setup-py to p4a
        # "in the future" --use-setup-py is going to be the default behaviour in p4a, right now it is not
        # Setting this to false will pass --ignore-setup-py, true will pass --use-setup-py
        # NOTE: this is general setuptools integration, having pyproject.toml is enough, no need to generate
        # setup.py if you're using Poetry, but you need to add "toml" to source.include_exts.
        #p4a.setup_py = false
         
        # (str) extra command line arguments to pass when invoking pythonforandroid.toolchain
        #p4a.extra_args =
         
         
         
        #
        # iOS specific
        #
         
        # (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
        #ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios
        # Alternately, specify the URL and branch of a git checkout:
        #ios.kivy_ios_url = https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
        #ios.kivy_ios_branch = master
         
        # Another platform dependency: ios-deploy
        # Uncomment to use a custom checkout
        #ios.ios_deploy_dir = ../ios_deploy
        # Or specify URL and branch
        #ios.ios_deploy_url = https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy
        #ios.ios_deploy_branch = 1.10.0
         
        # (bool) Whether or not to sign the code
        #ios.codesign.allowed = false
         
        # (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
        # Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
        #ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"
         
        # (str) The development team to use for signing the debug version
        #ios.codesign.development_team.debug = <hexstring>
         
        # (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
        #ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s
         
        # (str) The development team to use for signing the release version
        #ios.codesign.development_team.release = <hexstring>
         
        # (str) URL pointing to .ipa file to be installed
        # This option should be defined along with `display_image_url` and `full_size_image_url` options.
        #ios.manifest.app_url =
         
        # (str) URL pointing to an icon (57x57px) to be displayed during download
        # This option should be defined along with `app_url` and `full_size_image_url` options.
        #ios.manifest.display_image_url =
         
        # (str) URL pointing to a large icon (512x512px) to be used by iTunes
        # This option should be defined along with `app_url` and `display_image_url` options.
        #ios.manifest.full_size_image_url =
         
         
        [buildozer]
         
        # (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
        log_level = 2
         
        # (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
        warn_on_root = 1
         
        # (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
        # build_dir = ./.buildozer
         
        # (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .aab, .ipa) storage
        # bin_dir = ./bin
         
        #    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        #    List as sections
        #
        #    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
        #    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
        #    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
        #    Instead of doing:
        #
        #[app]
        #source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
        #
        #    This can be translated into:
        #
        #[app:source.exclude_patterns]
        #license
        #data/audio/*.wav
        #data/images/original/*
        #
         
         
        #    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        #    Profiles
        #
        #    You can extend section / key with a profile
        #    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
        #    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
        #    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
        #
        #[app@demo]
        #title = My Application (demo)
        #
        #[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
        #images/hd/*
        #
        #    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
        #
        #buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your spec file as well as the structure of your app directory as text and not as a link, particularly to pastebin links (as they'll often be deleted, rendering your post contextless.)

Comment: @ewokx the spec file is too long and i cannot paste it here cause it exceed the limit :(

I edited with folder structure

Comment: @ewokx I finally understood how to paste longer texts xD